# how to use paging in laravel

Tags: laravel, paging

I have a table `news`.

In my controller, I write:

```
public function datnuoc(){

    $tinxkldMoi1 = DB::table ( 'news' )->where ( 'datnuoc',1)->where('status',1)->orderBy('endDate', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);  
    $tinxkldMoi2 = DB::table ( 'news' )->where ( 'datnuoc',1)->take(5)->orderBy('endDate', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    $tinxkldMoi3 = DB::table ( 'news' )->where ( 'datnuoc',1)->where('status',3)->take(5)->orderBy('endDate', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);

    return View::make ( 'home/current',array(
            'tinxkldMois1'=> $tinxkldMoi1,
            'tinxkldMois2'=> $tinxkldMoi2,
            'tinxkldMois3'=> $tinxkldMoi3,

    ));
}
```

In the home/current view, I've written:

```
<php>
{{$tinxkldMois1->links()}}
{{$tinxkldMois2->links()}}
{{$tinxkldMois3->links()}}
</php>
```

How come when I click on one part it works, but not on the others?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `take()` and `paginate()` in the same query, both set the `limit`, so `take()` is being ignored. For the last two queries replace `paginate(20)` with `take(5)->get()`